# Networking - Using public IPs for servers without NAT

Tags: networking, routing, nat, switch

So I am curious to know how this is done...

Let's say your upstream provider has given you the following block of IPs 80.111.111.120/29 and for whatever reason you would like to use one of those IPs for a server.

Now you could do a 1 to 1 NAT using a router but I would like to know, how do you use one of those IPs directly on the server's NIC? I assume not any old router is going to cut it, if so what kind of switch/router would you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the way you'd do this is by using BGP to expose a route to your IP blocks through your router.  The route would be propagated out through your ISP to the world, and traffic to the backend IPs would be sent to one of the public IPs and your router would then forward them in.  Other than the role of BGP to dynamically expose routes, it's basically the same concept as having RFC 1918 subnets connected by a router on both subnets.

IN your case, you have only a /29 and so only have a few addresses, so probably this would be overkill.  In fact, you might not be able to even do it with your level of service.  I would recommend just connecting the NIC to your ISP and setting the public address if you want it to be online without NAT.

Comment: Ok cool thanks. I didn't know about BGP.

The /29 was for simplicities sake.